# How to make text all on the same line when adding div tags?

Tags: css, html

I have added div tags to text on the same line as I wanted to add the mouseover feature but now all the text is on different lines. How do I make it so all the text is on the same line?

HTML:

```
<div style="margin-top:30px;" />
<center>
<table height="50" width="400" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td>
<center>

<hr size="1" color="#585858" width="82%"></hr>

</center>
<center>
<div class="about">
<font face="helvetica" size="2" color="#585858">About Us</div>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<div class="about">Accessibility</div>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<div class="about">Contact Us</div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></div>

<font face="helvetica" size="2" color="#585858">&copy;2011&nbsp;-&nbsp;Privacy
</font></center>


</center>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</center>
```

CSS:

```
.about:hover {
font: 13px helvetica;
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Thanks!

James

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write `float:left` or `display:inline-block` in the `div css` because `div` is a `block element` that's why it comes below each other. So; that's why we use `float & inline-block` to force the `div` takes it's actual `width`:

```
div{
 float:left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! How do you center a div within a div?

Comment: give child div's display:inline-block & give there parent div text-align:center;

Answer (score 5):

A *div* generates a box and therefore a new line, try using *span* instead.

Additionally, you are using old, depreated HTML Tags like font or attributes like height/width.
Try to find some good tutorial about css and use css instead of html where possible.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are trying to create a horizontal list of links (except you haven't included the `<a>` elements yet).

The two general techniques are:

1. Use `float`
2. Use `display: inline-block`

You should also replace the div elements with list item elements. [Listamatic](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/) has many examples.

You should also [stop using layout tables](http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/), and replace the deprecated `<font>` and `<center>` elements with CSS, and use CSS `margins` instead of series of non-breaking spaces.

Answer (score 1):

are block level elements so they break the line and go into next line u can try with **float:left** or **float:right** or u can use **display:inline** feature .

Have a look at this example http://jsfiddle.net/T5rBU/ .

Also if u want to just have text inside div and align them in one line rather use span elements and they get aligned automatically.